# Getting The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request exception while calling WCF

Tags: wcf, exception

I am trying to call WCF method from my MVC application. While calling the WCF method, I am getting the "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request" error.

I am passing a list of items. if I am passing only 50, its going in, but if its morethan that, it is showing the error message.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

My client config:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
   <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPaymentRequestService" 
       closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
       sendTimeout="00:10:00"
       allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
       hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
       maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
       maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
       messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="StreamedRequest"
       useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas 
             maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
             maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
             maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Server Config:

```
<services>
  <service name="BasicHttpBinding_IPaymentRequestService"   >
    <endpoint name="BasicEndpoint" 
         address="http://localhost/Intel.IIP.WCF.Hosting/PaymentRequestServiceHost.svc" 
         binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding" 
         contract="IPaymentRequestService">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding >
    <binding name="ServiceBinding"  
         transferMode="StreamedRequest" allowCookies="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" 
         messageEncoding="Text" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8"  
         closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
         sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647"  
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
       <readerQuotas  
              maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
              maxDepth="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"  
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
       <security mode="None" ></security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Regards
Amal

Comment: Amal, I think we're missing the client configuration ... can you update? Also, check with something like the Service Trace Viewer (see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to see if you can get any more details.

Comment: Can you please show the rest of the client config?? Currently, there's only the binding there - what about the `<client>` section in your client-side config??

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
</system.web>
```